# Is there anything special about ip adressses 0.0.0.0 and 1.1.1.1

Tags: networking, ip-address

Someone asked me that IP Adress 0.0.0.0 is assigned to whom and used for what purpose.I didn't know the answer.It will be very helpful if someone helps me with this.Also about IP Adress 1.1.1.1.

Comment: See my answer [IP Address 0.0.0.0 is used or not?](http://superuser.com/a/869167)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address `0.0.0.0` is not routable as no network mask can be used to identify it.  Applying any network mask to it (with a `binary and`) will always return 0.

As for `1.1.1.1`, it is assigned to APNIC-LABS in Australia.  Since it is not linked to a domain name, it's probably used internally for their own private purposes.  An address ending with `.1` will often be a router, especially since this is the first address of the block.

Comment: @ Julie Pelletier can u explain the meaning of *not routable*

Comment: I updated my answer to give more details.

Answer (score 2):

**1.1.1.1 is a partnership between Cloudflare and APNIC as mentioned above, but there's more you should know.**

**First to explain who these companies are:**
Cloudflare runs one of the world’s largest, fastest networks. APNIC is a non-profit organization managing IP address allocation for the Asia Pacific and Oceania regions.

Cloudflare had the network. APNIC had the IP address (1.1.1.1). Both of us were motivated by a mission to help build a better Internet. You can read more about each organization’s motivations on our respective posts: Cloudflare Blog / APNIC Blog.

**Now to what this means:**
If you change your routing configuration on your computer to the addresses listed on their website, you will enjoy much faster DNS-Lookups. I just made this change today and I am completely amazed at the speed difference for more complex pages. The website is located at https://1.1.1.1 and contains all the information you need (including instructions).

**They are completely private and do NOT log DNS-lookups.**

**Caveat:** Please do not use them as a primary DNS if you are running a domain-membered computer or are using Outlook with Exchange. It will cause connectivity problems.

(I have no affiliation with these companies in any way, shape, or form and simply want to share this valuable information.)

Comment: Your caveat is intriguing. Can you provide a reference for this claim?